# Missing return at end of function

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I have a `getQueue()` function to create a connection and channel for my Go client to a RabbitMQ instance. I have this code for the aforementioned function:

```
func getQueue() (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue) {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://ayman@localhost:5672")
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to connect")
    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to open channel")
    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare("hello",
        false, //durable
        false, //autoDelete
        false, //exclusive
        false, //noWait
        nil)   //args
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to delare a queue")

}
```

I am getting this error `Missing return at end of function` for the same.
I tried using return keyboard at the end of the function, but then I get this error:

```
not enough arguments to return
have ()
want (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue)
```

The source video I was referring did not have any such issues.
I am using Ubuntu machine with Go version `go1.11.4 linux/amd64`. I am using Atom editor with `go-lang` tools package installed.

EDIT
The solution is that I needed 3 parameters to return
`return conn,ch,&q` solved my issue.

Comment: You are aware of that your function signature states that it will return `(*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue)`? If you don't want to return anything, you can issue a `return nil, nil, nil` (if this is your own function). But probably you want to `return conn, ch, q`.

Answer (score 1):

the (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue) part of your code says your function returns 3 things, but you don't return anything that is why you get the error. Try adding

```
return conn, ch, q
```

to your code that should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your function declares 3 return types, yet the code you presented has no [`return`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) statements.

You must either use the `return` statement to specify what values you want to return (on all possible return paths), e.g.:

```
func getQueue() (*amqp.Connection, *amqp.Channel, *amqp.Queue) {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://ayman@localhost:5672")
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to connect")
    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to open channel")
    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare("hello",
        false, //durable
        false, //autoDelete
        false, //exclusive
        false, //noWait
        nil)   //args
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to delare a queue")
    return conn, ch, q
}
```

Or you must use named result parameters, and then you can have a "naked" `return` statement (but you still must have a `return`), e.g.:

```
func getQueue() (conn *amqp.Connection, ch *amqp.Channel, q *amqp.Queue) {
    conn, err = amqp.Dial("amqp://ayman@localhost:5672")
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to connect")
    ch, err = conn.Channel()
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to open channel")
    q, err = ch.QueueDeclare("hello",
        false, //durable
        false, //autoDelete
        false, //exclusive
        false, //noWait
        nil)   //args
    fallOnError(err, "Fail to delare a queue")
    return
}
```

If you saw a video with this function declaration and no return statement, that code is also invalid. This does not depend on Go version or OS.